# Code template implementation with C#

Tags: c#, .net, code-generation, code-templates

When I need code template, I can use Python as follows.

```
templateString = """
%s 
%s
%s
"""

print templateString % ("a","b","c")
```

How do I implement the equivalent with C#?

I tried

```
using System;

class DoFile {

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string templateString = "
        {0}
        {1}
        {2}
        ";
        Console.WriteLine(templateString, "a", "b", "c");
    }
}
```

But I got

```
dogen.cs(86,0): error CS1010: Newline in constant
dogen.cs(87,0): error CS1010: Newline in constant
dogen.cs(88,0): error CS1010: Newline in constant
```

Of course `templateString = "{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n";` works, but I need to use multiple line template as the templateString is for generating a part of code, and it's really long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to place an `@` before the **first** quote

```
templateString = @"
        {0}
        {1}
        {2}
        ";
```

make it a **[verbatim-string-literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)**

> In a verbatim string literal, the
>   characters between the delimiters are
>   interpreted verbatim, the only
>   exception being a
>   quote-escape-sequence. In particular,
>   *simple escape sequences and
>   hexadecimal and Unicode escape
>   sequences* *are not processed* in
>   verbatim string literals. **A verbatim
>   string literal may span multiple
>   lines.**

Answer (score 3):

Do this instead (ad @ before the string constant):

```
class DoFile {

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string templateString = @"
        {0}
        {1}
        {2}
        ";
        Console.WriteLine(templateString, "a", "b", "c");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

U can put @ before the variable name to get multiline strings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put @ before the quotation marks for the string, this will make it a verbatim string literal and this will still use all of the whitespace you use.