# Putting \" in verbatim string with C#

Tags: c#, .net, stringtemplate, verbatim-string

I need to print

```
a
"b"
c
```

with the vebatim string, I posed another question about multiple line code template [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996218/code-template-implementation-with-c).

I tried with verbatim string as follows :

```
using System;

class DoFile {

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string templateString = @"
        {0}
        \\"{1}\\"
        {2}
        ";
        Console.WriteLine(templateString, "a", "b", "c");
    }
}
```

But, I got this error.

```
t.cs(8,11): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `{'
t.cs(9,0): error CS1010: Newline in constant
t.cs(10,0): error CS1010: Newline in constant
```

`\"{1}\"` doesn't work neither.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this ( "" instead of " to escape )

```
string templateString = @"
        {0}
        ""{1}""
        {2}
        ";
```

From C# specification: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa691090

> quote-escape-sequence:
>       ""

Answer (score 8):

In a verbatim string literal you use `""` for double quote characters.

```
string line = @"
{0}
""{1}""
{2}";
```

Answer (score 4):

When using a multi-line string literal in C# with `@"`, the correct escape sequence for a double-quote becomes `""` instead of `\"`.

```
    string templateString = @"
    {0}
    ""{1}""
    {2}
    ";
```

Answer (score 1):

In a verbatim string, use `""` for a `"` in the result.

Answer (score 1):

In an `@"` string, embedded double quotes are escaped as `""`,not `\"`. Change your code to

```
    string templateString = @"
    {0}
    ""{1}""
    {2}
    ";
```

and your problems should go away.

Comment: Then lose the backslash. Edited to reflect the change.

Answer (score 0):

```
string templateString = @"        
{0}        
""{1}""
{2}
";
```

EDIT: Updated to show correct syntax when using Verbatim.

Comment: Incorrect.  OP already notes this is wrong...

Comment: @mellamokb - thanks - I will check my syntax first

Answer (score 0):

Use a "double double" quote to produce a single double quote in the output. It's the same way old VB6 would process strings.

```
@" ""something"" is here";
```

contains a string that has quotes around the something.